# PromiseKit optional chaining Swift

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

How I can make Optional promises chaining?
e.g., I have two promises and I have to check second only by some conditions from first promise results.

```
promise1(). then { result -> Promise? in
if result.success {
return promise2()
}
return nil
}
.then { secondResult -> Void in

}
.always {...}
.catch ...
```

But when I write something like this compiler thinks that type of is Promise?, not Any (bit "Any" I mean any other class/structure)

So, how I can make some kind of chaining? And there should be one always and one catch handlers as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
let p = Promise<Int>() { fulffill, reject in
  fulffill(0)
}.then { result -> Promise<Any>? in
  if result == 0 {
    return Promise(value: 5)
  } else if result == 1 {
    return Promise(value: "test")
  } else {
    return nil
  }
}.then { secondResult -> Void in
  print("\(secondResult?.value)")
}.always {
  print("Final!")
}
```

If *result* is 0 the *secondResult.value* will be Int with value of 5, if *result* is 1 the *secondResult.value* will be "test". Then you can use the result in the second Promise to make the decision.

Comment: thanks, but PromiseKit doesn't provide returning optional Promises, I have asked them at github